# What happens if a site "flattens" the location types in CiviCRM?

Tags: location-type

CiviCRM has multiple location types ("home", "work", "postal", "billing").

The contact DB I'm working with has no distinction, and the types don't add value for this contact. The location types were renamed as "Location 1", "Location 2", etc during data import. The client desires to eliminate the need to choose a given location type.

I believe there are some parts of CiviCRM which still expect a dedicated "Billing" location type, however ([eg search for `CRM_Core_BAO_LocationType::getBilling()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CRM_Core_BAO_LocationType%3A%3AgetBilling)).

- What expectations does CiviCRM make about a dedicated Billing address type? AFAICT, this is somewhat "magic" in that [`CRM_Core_BAO_LocationType::getBilling()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/21cea480ee729320e15c71abdfa47f84a6bbdece/CRM/Core/BAO/LocationType.php#L108) looks for a location type with a name of "Billing".
- What issues arise if the Billing location type is renamed or deleted?
- What other considerations might there be when modifying CiviCRM's builtin location types?